# how to use UIImageView in iphone application development?

Tags: iphone

i have dragged a `UIImageView` into a view and created an `IBOutlet` object in the header file of the `UIViewController`.

In the Image View Control, I chose the image from the properties window, but when I launch the application, it does not show the image!

How can I fix this?

Comment: change the background color of the image view to see whether it is displayed at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.
I think the problem was with some image files that wont be displayed!! I resaved them and it's working now.

Thanks again

Comment: this is considered a comment or edited into your initial question, please do no add answers with comments because stackoverflow is different to common forums

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to connect the UIImageView to your IBOutlet. Ctrl+Click your UIViewController under the objects pane and drag the line to the UIImageView. Let go and connect it to the object.